# Как сконвертировать изображение из из буквенно-цифрового набора в формат jpg или png

Tags: javascript, изображения, конвертация, обработка-изображений

Получаю код такого формата, в нем изображение, как его преборазовать в файл jpg или png?

`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcGBwcICQsJCAgKCAcHCg0KCgsMDAwMBwkODw0MDgsMDAz/2wBDAQICAgMDAwYDAwYMCAcIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAz//gA9Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NjIpLCBxdWFsaXR5ID0gMTAwCgD/wAARCAMgAyADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUp`

Comment: функция window.atob()

Comment: @Виктор , а как ее использовать? она мне раскодировала элемент в такой набор цифр и букв, но в другом составе.

Comment: Поищи в google "javascript atob"

Comment: не картинка похоже это. <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR...."/>

Comment: в общем, в бд ее сохраняю как есть. из бд нормально подсасывает на фронт. изображение видно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR...';
    document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Вообще-то в вашем base64 изображение битой ссылки, но для примера возьмём что-нибудь другое.

```js
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Comment: спасибо за пример !